# Rule between environments (no spacing!)

Tags: tables, spacing, rules

I want to place a rule between two centered `tabular`s like the following example.
But I am not able to control the correct spacing of 2mm in between the rule.
Can somebody maybe explain :-) what should be added and why the several spacing commands should be added to obtain the result of 2mm vertical space between the rules?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
    {\centering%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ASBSCSM}%
    \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Name && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Vorname && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}ETH-Nummer && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Studiengang \\[0.6cm]%
    \end{tabularx}%
    }
   \vspace{2mm}%
   \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}%
   \vspace{2mm}%
   {\centering%
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ASBSCSM}%
        \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Name && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Vorname && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}ETH-Nummer && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Studiengang \\[0.6cm]%
        \end{tabularx}%
   }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, make the MWE self-contained; it's not possible to compile it, as the `ABCSM` column types are not defined.

Answer (score 5):

```
  {\centering%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ASBSCSM}%
    \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Name && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Vorname && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}ETH-Nummer && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Studiengang \\[0.6cm]%
    \end{tabularx}%
    }
```

will not center anything as the centering ends at the `}` before th eparagraph ends, it does have a side effect of suppressing paragraph indentation (or at least making it 0) which is needed for a full width table, but it is probably simpler to use `\noindent` or just use a single `\centering` at the start of the environment with no extra `{}`.

`\rule` will start a new line of a paragraph so you get inter-line `\baselineskip` which you don't really want.

You need to use `\vspace{2mm}` between paragraphs or the space comes after the current line, which usually isn't where you want it. (As posted in your example the entire float with both tabularx and the rule is all a single paragraph.)

this is untested as your posted code can not be run but

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ASBSCSM}%
    \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Name && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Vorname && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}ETH-Nummer && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Studiengang
    \end{tabularx}

   \vspace{2mm}
\hrule
   \vspace{2mm}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ASBSCSM}%
        \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Name && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Vorname && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}ETH-Nummer && \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Studiengang
        \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
```